# How to intersection to 3D polygons by Boost C++ library?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-geometry

I want to intersect two 3D polygons, my compiler is VC++2013.
I want to use Boost geometry library. But how to do this? I've tried the following:

```
#include <boost/geometry/geometry.hpp> 
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/register/point.hpp> 
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/register/ring.hpp> 


struct MyPoint
{
    double x, y, z;
};

BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_POINT_3D(MyPoint, double, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian, x, y, z)

typedef boost::geometry::model::polygon<MyPoint> Polygon;

BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_RING(Polygon::ring_type)

......

int main()
{
    using boost::geometry::append;
    using boost::geometry::correct;
    using boost::geometry::dsv;

    Polygon poly1;
    Polygon poly2;

    append(poly1, MyPoint{ 2, 0, 1 });
    append(poly1, MyPoint{ 2, 2, 1 });
    append(poly1, MyPoint{ 0, 2, 1 });
    append(poly1, MyPoint{ 0, 0, 1 });
    append(poly1, MyPoint{ 2, 0, 1 });

    append(poly2, MyPoint{ 3, 0, 1 });
    append(poly2, MyPoint{ 3, 3, 1 });
    append(poly2, MyPoint{ 0, 3, 1 });
    append(poly2, MyPoint{ 0, 0, 1 });
    append(poly2, MyPoint{ 3, 0, 1 });

    correct(poly1);
    correct(poly2);

    std::vector<Polygon> polys;


    if (boost::geometry::intersection(poly1, poly2, polys))
    {
        for (Polygon const& inter : polys)
            std::cout << "Intersection polygon area is " << boost::geometry::area(inter) << " with " << dsv(inter) << "\n";
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Why is it not working, what error do you get. Can you include it in your question for the sake of completeness?

Answer (score 0):

No this appears to be unimplemented.

E.g. `area(Polygon)` simply asserts that the dimensions must equal 2. That implicitly means that `correct` doesn't support 3d geometries, and though the `intersection` algorithm triggeres different errors (first) it stands to reason that the root cause is still the same.

Quoting the OGC "Simple Feature" specification that Boost Geometry implements:

> #### §6.1.2.5 Use of Z and M coordinate values
>
> A Point value may include a z coordinate value. The z coordinate value traditionally represents the
>   third dimension (i.e. 3D). [...]
>
> Spatial operations work in the "map geometry" of the data and will
>   therefore not reflect z or m values in calculations (e.g., Equals,
>   Length) or in generation of new geometry values (e.g., Buffer,
>   ConvexHull, Intersection). This is done by projecting the geometric
>   objects onto the horizontal plane to obtain a "footprint" or "shadow"
>   of the objects for the purposed of map calculations. In other words,
>   it is possible to store and obtain z (and m) coordinate values but
>   they are ignored in all other operations which are based on map
>   geometries. **Implementations are free to include true 3D geometric
>   operations, but should be consistent with ISO 19107**.