# Map-geometry intersection of two 3d linestrings using Boost

Tags: c++, boost

I'm trying to determine the point of intersection between two 3d linestring using Boost, but in certain cases I'm not getting the expected result.

From my understanding [1], Boost should be calculating the intersection using *Map geometry* - that is, the Z coordinate is not considered.  This is the functionality I'm after.

However, my testing shows if one linestring is always above the other (case 1 in the code listing below), then I get no intersections.

But, if the second line crosses the plane containing the first line - case 2 - then an intersection is found - even though the two lines don't intersect in 3d space.

Is my understanding wrong? Or, is there a way to make case 1 work?

My workaround has been to ensure the first linestring will *always* cross the plane of the second... But it seems hacky.

Thanks

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/geometries.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/algorithms/intersection.hpp>

namespace bg = boost::geometry;

int main()
{
    typedef bg::model::point<double, 3, bg::cs::cartesian> point_t;
    typedef bg::model::linestring<point_t> linestring_t;

    linestring_t ls1{{0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1}};
    linestring_t ls2{{0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}};
    linestring_t ls3{{0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1}};

    std::vector<point_t> intersections;

    bg::intersection(ls1, ls2, intersections);


    std::cout << "Case 1: Intersection between l1 and l2? " << (intersections.size() > 0 ? "Yes" : "No") << std::endl;

    bg::intersection(ls1, ls3, intersections);
    std::cout << "Case 2: Intersection between l1 and l3? " << (intersections.size() > 0 ? "Yes" : "No") << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
Case 1: Intersection between l1 and l2? No
Case 2: Intersection between l1 and l3? Yes
```

References:

[1] "How to intersection to 3D polygons by Boost C++ library?", https://stackoverflow.com/a/49012544/338230

Answer (score 1):

The linked answer merely states that

- Boost Geometry `area` did support implement dimensions>2¹
- The OGM standard allows conforming implementations to work in map geometry, although they can implement full 3d geometry, as long as it is consistent with another standard.

I can't find anything different with regards to `intersection` today. It is rather surprising to me that the documentation doesn't clearly warn against unspecified behaviour.

However, it would appear that the only way to get map-geo behavior is by manually mapping:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1e23b3ef362706e1)**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/geometries.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/algorithms/intersection.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/multi_point.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/algorithms/for_each.hpp>

namespace bg = boost::geometry;
static inline constexpr auto io = [](auto& g) { return bg::dsv(g); }; // switch to bg::wkt easily
using point_t      = bg::model::point<double, 3, bg::cs::cartesian>;
using points_t     = bg::model::multi_point<point_t>;
using linestring_t = bg::model::linestring<point_t>;

struct ZeroZ {
    inline void operator()(point_t& p)          const  { p.set<2>(0);                  } 
    template <typename G> void operator()(G& g) const  { bg::for_each_point(g, *this); } 
} static inline constexpr zeroz{};

int main() {
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2);

    linestring_t const lss[] = {
        {{0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1}},
        {{0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}},
        {{0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1}},
    };

    for (auto a : lss) for (auto b : lss) {
        points_t c, d;
        bg::intersection(a, b, c);

        std::cout << "Normal:  " << io(a) << " with " << io(b) << " ->" << io(c) << "\n";
        zeroz(a);
        zeroz(b);

        bg::intersection(a, b, d);
        if (!bg::equals(c, d))
            std::cout << " -- but: " << io(a) << " with " << io(b) << " ->" << io(d) << "\n";
    }
}
```

Prints

```
Normal:  ((0.00, 0.00, 1.00), (1.00, 1.00, 1.00)) with ((0.00, 0.00, 1.00), (1.00, 1.00, 1.00)) ->((0.00, 0.00, 1.00), (1.00, 1.00, 1.00))
 -- but: ((0.00, 0.00, 0.00), (1.00, 1.00, 0.00)) with ((0.00, 0.00, 0.00), (1.00, 1.00, 0.00)) ->((0.00, 0.00, 0.00), (1.00, 1.00, 0.00))
Normal:  ((0.00, 0.00, 0.00), (1.00, 1.00, 0.00)) with ((0.00, 1.00, 0.00), (1.00, 0.00, 0.00)) ->((0.50, 0.50, 0.00))
Normal:  ((0.00, 0.00, 0.00), (1.00, 1.00, 0.00)) with ((0.00, 1.00, 0.00), (1.00, 0.00, 1.00)) ->((0.50, 0.50, 0.00))
Normal:  ((0.00, 1.00, 0.00), (1.00, 0.00, 0.00)) with ((0.00, 0.00, 1.00), (1.00, 1.00, 1.00)) ->()
 -- but: ((0.00, 1.00, 0.00), (1.00, 0.00, 0.00)) with ((0.00, 0.00, 0.00), (1.00, 1.00, 0.00)) ->((0.50, 0.50, 0.00))
Normal:  ((0.00, 1.00, 0.00), (1.00, 0.00, 0.00)) with ((0.00, 1.00, 0.00), (1.00, 0.00, 0.00)) ->((0.00, 1.00, 0.00), (1.00, 0.00, 0.00))
Normal:  ((0.00, 1.00, 0.00), (1.00, 0.00, 0.00)) with ((0.00, 1.00, 0.00), (1.00, 0.00, 1.00)) ->((0.00, 1.00, 0.00), (1.00, 0.00, 0.00))
Normal:  ((0.00, 1.00, 0.00), (1.00, 0.00, 1.00)) with ((0.00, 0.00, 1.00), (1.00, 1.00, 1.00)) ->((0.50, 0.50, 0.00))
Normal:  ((0.00, 1.00, 0.00), (1.00, 0.00, 0.00)) with ((0.00, 1.00, 0.00), (1.00, 0.00, 0.00)) ->((0.00, 1.00, 0.00), (1.00, 0.00, 0.00))
Normal:  ((0.00, 1.00, 0.00), (1.00, 0.00, 0.00)) with ((0.00, 1.00, 0.00), (1.00, 0.00, 1.00)) ->((0.00, 1.00, 0.00), (1.00, 0.00, 0.00))
```

¹ at the time, not even checked whether that changed

Comment: Thank you for your answer - including the excellent snippets!  I think I'm going to have to reorganise my code and store the heights separately.

Comment: You may not need to: by definition BG's extensibility make it possible to adapt any 3d point as a 2d type. Just keep in mind that any output of the algorithm will lose the z coordinate /unless/ it is a reference (view) of a source point